# Bootstraps issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Excuse me. Is there any issues with Bootstraps when using CSS3 (I can't remove bootstraps because they're needed for my site). Here is the [code](https://codepen.io/loctran016/pen/poNJWRy):

```html
  <form onsubmit="submitFn(this, event);">
    <div id="search-wrapper">
        <div id="input-holder">
            <input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Type to search" />
            <button id="search-icon" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"><span></span></button>
        </div>
        <span id="close" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"></span>
        <div id="result-container">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```css
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover; background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: aqua;
}
#search-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}
#search-wrapper.active {}

#search-wrapper #input-holder {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 70px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    border-radius:6px;
    position: relative;
    width:70px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#search-wrapper.active #input-holder {
    border-radius: 50px;
    width:450px;
    background: rgba(34, 215, 228, 0.5);
    -webkit-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
    -moz-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
    transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
}

#search-wrapper #input-holder #search-input {
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding:0px 70px 0 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    font-family:"Open Sans", Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
    color:#FFF;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 60px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 60px);
    transform: translate(0, 60px);
    -webkit-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
    -moz-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);

    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
#search-wrapper.active #input-holder #search-input {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 10px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 10px);
    transform: translate(0, 10px);
}

#search-wrapper #input-holder #search-icon {
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    border:none;
    border-radius:6px;
    background: #FFF;
    padding:0px;
    outline:none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    float:right;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#search-wrapper.active #input-holder #search-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
#search-wrapper #input-holder #search-icon span {
    width:22px !important;
    height:22px !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    position:relative !important;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
    transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.650, -0.600, 0.240, 1.650) !important;
    -moz-transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.650, -0.600, 0.240, 1.650) !important;
    transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.650, -0.600, 0.240, 1.650) !important;

}
#search-wrapper.active #input-holder #search-icon span {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) !important;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) !important;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) !important;
}
#search-wrapper #input-holder #search-icon span::before, #search-wrapper #input-holder #search-icon span::after {
    position: absolute !important;
    content:'' !important;
}
#search-wrapper #input-holder #search-icon span::before {
    width: 4px !important;
    height: 11px !important;
    left: 9px !important;
    top: 18px !important;
    border-radius: 2px !important;
    background: aqua !important;
}
#search-wrapper #input-holder #search-icon span::after {
    width: 14px !important;
    height: 14px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    border-radius: 16px !important;
    border: 4px solid aqua !important;
}

#search-wrapper #close {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top:24px;
    right:20px;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -webkit-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.285, -0.450, 0.935, 0.110);
    -moz-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.285, -0.450, 0.935, 0.110);
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.285, -0.450, 0.935, 0.110);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
#search-wrapper.active #close {
    right:-50px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
    -moz-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
    transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.5s;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
#search-wrapper #close::before, #search-wrapper #close::after {
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
#search-wrapper #close::before {
    width: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 0px;
}
#search-wrapper #close::after {
    width: 25px;
    height: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 10px;
}
#search-wrapper #result-container {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:80px;
    left:0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    display:none;
    color:#B7B7B7;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
    #search-wrapper.active #input-holder {width:200px;}
}
```

```js
function searchToggle(obj, evt) {
  const container = $(obj).closest('#search-wrapper');

  if (!container.hasClass('active')) {
    container.addClass('active');
    evt.preventDefault();
  } else if (container.hasClass('active') && $(obj)
      .closest('#input-holder').length == 0) {
    container.removeClass('active');
    // clear input
    container.find('#search-input').val('');
    // clear and hide result container when we press close
    container.find('#result-container').fadeOut(100, function() {
      $(this).empty();
    });
  }
}

function submitFn(obj, evt) {
  value = $(obj).find('#search-input').val().trim();

  _html = 'Searching for: ';
  if (!value.length) {
    _html = 'Ehem, I can\'t search nothing';
  } else {
    _html += '<b>' + value + '</b>';
  }

  $(obj).find('#result-container').html('<span>' + _html + '</span>');
  $(obj).find('#result-container').fadeIn(100);

  evt.preventDefault();
}
```

Here is a picture if I don't use bootstrap:
[Dont't use bootstraps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYsZC.png)

And here is the picture if I use bootstrap:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iATkf.png)

I'm quite a newbie and I have learnt to code this on the internet. I appreciated your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure out adding `box-sizing: content-box !important;` to every things have `::after`, `::before` help this